# Swift compile error: "cannot load underlying module for 'CoreGraphics'" with `import Foundation`

Tags: swift, macos, compiler-errors, foundation, swift3

With Swift `DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a`, I'm trying to build a project using `swift build` but as soon as I add the line `import Foundation` I get the error:

```
[I] ~/Dropbox/Projects/test                                                     
↪ swift build --clean; and swift build
Compiling Swift Module 'test' (1 sources)
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'CoreGraphics'
<unknown>:0: note: did you forget to set an SDK using -sdk or SDKROOT?
<unknown>:0: note: use "xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc" to select the default OS X SDK installed with Xcode
<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures
error: exit(1): ["/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool", "-f", "/Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/test/.build/debug/test.o/llbuild.yaml"]
```

Running `xcrun -sdk macosx` results in "no such SDK: 'machos'" error:

```
↪ xcrun -sdk macosx swift build                                       0@10:34:03
<unknown>:0: warning: no such SDK: 'macosx'
<unknown>:0: warning: no such sysroot directory: 'macosx'
<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'Darwin'
error: exit(1): ["/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc", "--driver-mode=swift", "-I", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-L", "/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-02-08-a.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm", "-lPackageDescription", "-target", "x86_64-apple-macosx10.10", "/Users/me/Dropbox/Projects/test/Package.swift"]
```

This is with only main.swift, whose contents are:

```
import Foundation

print("Hello, world!")
```

No dependencies are defined in Packages.swift.

Really don't know what's going on here. This compiles fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 DigitalOcean VPS as well as within Xcode 7.3 Beta 5.

OS X 10.11.3

```
↪ swift --version                                                     0@10:21:16
Apple Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM a7663bb722, Clang 4ca3c7fa28, Swift 1c2f40e246)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the stable release of Xcode.app in your [/Applications] directory? If you just have Xcode-beta.app, that's likely what's causing this error. Try creating a symlink of Xcode-beta.app to Xcode.app:

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app /Applications/Xcode.app
```

(Kudos to [anton](https://zewo.slack.com/messages/help/team/anton/) for [the answer](https://zewo.slack.com/archives/help/p1457744573002694)).

Comment: No, I deleted Xcode.app once I got Xcode-beta.app working. This worked for me! Thank you!